# Nhibernate Lazy load on multiple columns

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

If I set LazyLoad on multiple properties-columns with NHiberante and access those properties one after the other, would it query the database for each property?
Example:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ID {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual string FullName {get; set;}
    public virtual float Price {get; set;}
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    Id(p => p.ID);
    Map(p => p.Name).Not.LazyLoad();
    Map(p => p.FullName).LazyLoad(); // Redundant - I know...
    Map(p => p.Price).LazyLoad();    // Redundant - I know...
}
```

---

if I query the DB like this:

```
var product = session.Load<Prodct>(2);
if (product.FullName == "*" && product.Price = 111)
```

Will there be 3 queries

1. The Product entity
2. The FullName property
3. The Price property

or when NHibernate query the DB for FullName it will query all the columns of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate will load all the lazy properties of an entity in a single query (you can try for yourself...)

The main use case for this feature is blobs.

Lazy *references*, on the other hand, are loaded as needed.

As a side note, `session.Load` does not query the DB; it just creates a proxy, which will be loaded lazily. Use `session.Get`.

Comment: This is what I see as well, so There will be two queries right? Hope this dissuction will be shorter then that are handling in other thread. **;-)**

Comment: Yes, you'll have one query for the non-lazy properties, and one for all the lazy ones.

Answer (score 2):

there will be 2 queries

1. The Product entity
2. All LazyLoaded Properties